# Having trouble with MySQL Command 'LOAD DATA INFILE". I need to set first row as headers

Tags: mysql

Here is my code.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE dsw_data.inventory_sss2;
SET AUTOCOMMIT=0; 
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/inetpub/wwwroot/Data/inventory_sss.csv' INTO TABLE dsw_data.inventory_sss2 FIELDS TERMINATED BY  ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r'; 
COMMIT;
```

Here is the resulting error

```
Error Code: 1366. Incorrect integer value: 'CUST NO' for column 'sno' at row 1"
```

I want the first row of the CSV to be the table headers, and the other rows to be the data.

Also how do I specify which rows should be numeric (If this is even needed, I'm not sure).

I have searched here and google, but haven't seen code samples to set the headers like I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your first question, you need to use the `IGNORE 1 LINES` syntax:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE dsw_data.inventory_sss2;
SET AUTOCOMMIT=0; 
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/inetpub/wwwroot/Data/inventory_sss.csv' 
INTO TABLE dsw_data.inventory_sss2 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY  ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r'; 
IGNORE 1 LINES
COMMIT;
```

Updated to explicitly name the columns and set the primary key to null to use auto-increment:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE dsw_data.inventory_sss2;
SET AUTOCOMMIT=0; 
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/inetpub/wwwroot/Data/inventory_sss.csv' 
INTO TABLE dsw_data.inventory_sss2 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY  ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r'; 
IGNORE 1 LINES
(your_first_column, your_second_column,...)
SET sno = NULL
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Thanks. That seemed to work to skip the first line, but now it's not letting me have duplicate content in the first row. Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '1212' for key 'PRIMARY' Also I assume I need to have the table headers set up ahead of time using this method. My table does have a first column named 'sno' Which I assume should be the primary key column, but my CSV doesn't contain data for that column.

Comment: Since the columns in the CSV do not exactly match the columns in your table, you should explicitly name the columns in order in the `LOAD DATA INFILE` statement. Furthermore you can explicitly `SET sno = NULL` if it is auto-increment.

Comment: Thank you! I will test this in the next 30 minutes and get back to you. @Ike Walker

Comment: Worked great. Thank you so much! @Ike Walker

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
IGNORE 1 LINES
```

to your `LOAD DATA` query as such:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/inetpub/wwwroot/Data/inventory_sss.csv' INTO TABLE dsw_data.inventory_sss2 FIELDS TERMINATED BY  ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r' IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

You do not need to specify which fields are numeric, it will based on the table you are loading into.

Comment: Thanks. That seemed to work to skip the first line, but now it's not letting me have duplicate content in the first row.

    `Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '1212' for key 'PRIMARY'`

Also I assume I need to have the table headers set up ahead of time using this method.

Comment: My table does have a first column named 'sno' Which I assume should be the primary key column, but my CSV doesn't contain data for that column.

Comment: Welcome. Glad I could shed some light on your issue.