# How to empty a table before MySQL import

Tags: mysql, import, truncate

We want to empty the table before importing the new .csv.   In Oracle you can tell it to truncate the table in the control file.  Is there something similar in MySQL?

This is my current statement:

```
mysql --host=localhost --user=$USER --password=$PASS --database=$DB<<EOFMYSQL
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$file' REPLACE INTO TABLE daily_import FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Comment: This? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803364/having-trouble-with-mysql-command-load-data-infile-i-need-to-set-first-row-as

Comment: Truncate is present in all versions of sql that I know of and it doesn't take much searching to find https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/truncate-table.html

Comment: Very nice.  Thank you.  Was not 100% sure that I could put more than one command in that line between the tags.     Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Before insert query you could write above this truncate command.

mysql -u $DB_USER -p$DB_PASSWORD $DB_NAME --execute="TRUNCATE `$_table_name`"

mysql --host=localhost --user=$USER --password=$PASS --database=$DB<